# Как запускать скрипты последовательно через yarn?

Tags: webpack, npm, yarn

```js
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --mode development",
    "server": "json-server --watch --port 4000 src/server/db.json",
    "start": "yarn run server && yarn run dev"
  }
```

Вот кусок из **package.json**. Пробовал устанавливать **npm-run-all**. Но всё равно не работает. Запускает скрипт один из двух и всё. На следующий не переключается. Также запускал через npm. Тоже не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливаем зависимость **yarn add concurrently**. В **package.json** прописываем скрипт:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"yarn run dev\" \"yarn run server\"",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --mode development",
    "server": "json-server --watch --port 4000 src/server/db.json"
  }
```